# Im not able to automate discord webhook python

Tags: python, discord

**What does it need to do?:**

A fairly simple script pulls info from RSS feed and posts it via discord_webhook, in a discord channel. This works fine. However, the entries must be "updated" after a certain time. Thus, the old webhook message is deleted and the new message sent or edited.

**What is the problem?:**

The problem is that the message will be removed however on the "repost" it posted the previous one too. I have researched this and found some answers but nothing that could resolve the issue in a code sense. (I'm not too experienced with coding).

**I tried:**

Reviewing my code from a logic perspective it doesn't seem to be caused by the code itself, but more like a thing with the discord_webhook.py, I'm not doing right when sending multiple messages(Loop).
As I said, I have seen some solutions but not able to use them to change my code or get what needs to be changed.

**The code:**

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import feedparser
from time import sleep


#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# Vars
#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='')


#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# Functies
#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
def main(webhook):
    # Main function , calling other functions

    # Send first message
    message_send(webhook)
    # Time to wait before refresh
    sleep(10)
    # Remove the old message
    message_remove(webhook)


def message_send(webhook):
    # Send message thru webhook

    # Get the info from the RSS feed function
    entry = info_get()

    # Create embed message for the webhook
    embed = DiscordEmbed(title="Report", description="Repeatable report", color="14177041")
    embed.set_author(name='NCSC')
    embed.set_footer(text='https://www.ncsc.nl/')
    for i in entry:
        embed.add_embed_field(name=i[0], value=i[1], inline=False)
    embed.set_timestamp()
    webhook.add_embed(embed)
    
    # Send message
    response = webhook.execute()


def message_remove(webhook):
    # Removes the old message
    webhook.delete(webhook)
    

def info_get():
    list = []
    # Get the information thru RSS feed
    info = feedparser.parse("https://advisories.ncsc.nl/rss/advisories")

    # Use the first 4 entries
    entry = info.entries[: 4]

    # List only the title and link, rest is not needed
    for i in entry:
        list.append([i.title, i.link])
    return list



#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# Runs
#=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# Loop the main function
while True:
    main(webhook)
```

**The result in discord after the first refresh:**

This is the result of the script that keeps stacking messages.

Note: sleep(10) is normally sleep(3600)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/490928227163045888/795927426122121266/unknown.png

If anything comes to your mind please let me know, even things that simply could improve my code since I'm trying my best to learn.

Thank you,

Greetings.

Comment: You're not using the official discord.py library here, why did you tag it?

Comment: I didn't even think about that, StackOverflow suggested it, thank you for notifying me. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the official `discord.py` library.

Note: Unfornatelly you **CANNOT** delete messages with a webhook, the simplest way would be to edit the message (you need `discord.py` v. 1.6 or above)

```py
import aiohttp
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

intents = discord.Intents.default() # Enabling default intents, change it accordingly to your needs
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) # If you also want commands use `commands.Bot`
previous_message_id = None # Just a placeholder

@tasks.loop(seconds=10) # Or whatever interval you want
async def bg_task(webhook):
    global previous_message_id
    """Will edit a message every 10 seconds (if there is one)"""
    if previous_message_id is None:
        # Sending a new message
        message = await webhook.send('Hello World', username='Foo', wait=True)
        previous_message_id = message.id

    else:
        # Editing the previous message sent by the webhook
        await webhook.edit_message(previous_message_id, content='Whatever')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    # Creating a session and getting the webhook
    client.session = aiohttp.ClientSession() 
    webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url('url-here', adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(client.session))
    # Starting the task
    bg_task.start(webhook)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run('TOKEN')
```

### Reference:

- [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [`discord.Webhook.from_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Webhook.from_url)
- [`discord.Webhook.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Webhook.send)
- [`discord.Webhook.edit_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook%20edit_message#discord.Webhook.edit_message)

Comment: Damn you work quick :O, I was just about to ask, how to delete the previous message.

Comment: Haha, remember to accept the answer if it helped, also - the previous message attribute is going to reset whenever the bot restarts and you won't be able to delete it

Comment: First of all, thank you I didn't even think of it this way.
Second I get this error. AttributeError: 'Webhook' object has no attribute 'previous_message'. Do you happen to know why I get this error?

Comment: Hm, that's weird, also, sorry - I just realized that webhooks cannot delete messages, only edit (in d.py 1.6) I'll update my answer for that if you want.

Comment: No probs, like I said, now I have something to work with :)